# AngularJs if statement in ng-href

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have some elements which are created dynamically and every element has a different ng-href.

I want to give different link according to some elements.

When I try to write function in ng-href it sends the page to function in url,therefore it does not work.

I try to do something  like this;

```
       .......
             <a 
            ng-href='if(m){#linkOne} else {#linkTwo}'
            ng-click='test(type);'>

              </a> 
       .......
```

Which method should i use to create element with different ng-href?

Answer (score 22):

You can try this

```
<a ng-href="{{m ? '#linkOne':'#linkTwo'}}" ng-click="test(type)">your link</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/54ema4k0/

Answer (score 5):

Just do like this its very simple.

```
<a href="{{variable == value ? '#link1' : '#link2'}}">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a variable for the link

```
<a ng-href='{{link}}' ng-click='test(type);'> your link </a>
```

then

```
$scope.$watch('m', function(value){
    $scope.link = value ? 'link1': 'link2';
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2Lvxa8br/)

Answer (score 0):

Try conditional operator

```
<a ng-href='m ? "link1" : "link2" ' ng-click='test(type);'> your link </a>
```

or

set your link value in scope,

in your controller,

```
$scope.dynamic_url = 'somelink'
```

in view,

```
<a ng-href='dynamic_url' ng-click='test(type);'> your link </a>
```

Comment: conditional operator does not work,it sends to " m ? "link1" : "link2"   " in url

Comment: where you declare & define m scope ?