# make href url dynamic with angular with two same href link to a single href link

Tags: html, angularjs

below is my html code, I need href should be dynamic based on my current state and instead of using two different divs I can with one div only

```
<div ng-if="ctrl.currentState == 'employee'">
    <small><a href="/createQuote" title="Change Settings"></a></small>
</div>
<div ng-if="ctrl.currentState == 'fleetmanager'">
        <small><a href="/createQuote/fleetmanager" title="Change Settings"></a></small>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngHref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)

```
<small><a ng-href="{{myLink}}" title="Change Settings"></a></small>
```

And in your controller

```
$scope.myLink = $scope.currentState == 'employee' ? '/createQuote' : '/createQuote/fleetmanager';
```

This way is a bit better, because this part can be covered with unit tests as well.

But if you want to place this logic into template, [check out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888624/angularjs-if-statement-in-ng-href) similar question