# how to make URL dynamic using angularJs

Tags: html, angularjs

Need to make this three anchor tag into a single one and href need to be dynamic. Below is my code:

```
<a ng-if="ctrl.currentState == 'driver'" id="back-button" href="/driver/quoting/app/search/"></a>
<a ng-if="ctrl.currentState == 'employee'" id="employeeBackButton" href="/driver/quoting/app/employee/search"></a>
<a ng-if="ctrl.currentState == 'fleetmanager'" id="fleetmanagerBackButton" href="/driver/quoting/app/fleetmanager/search"></a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make href url dynamic with angular with two same href link to a single href link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54143654/make-href-url-dynamic-with-angular-with-two-same-href-link-to-a-single-href-link)

Comment: `<a ng-attr-id="{{buttonname}}" ng-href="{{address}}"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngHref` here

```
// In your controller 

if ($scope.currentState) == 'driver') {
    $scope.myUrl = '/driver/quoting/app/search/';
    $scope.myButtonId = 'back-button';
else if ($scope.currentState == 'employee') {  
    $scope.myUrl = '/driver/quoting/app/employee/search';
    $scope.myButtonId = 'employeeBackButton';
else if ($scope.currentState == 'fleetmanager') {  
    $scope.myUrl = '/driver/quoting/app/fleetmanager/search';        
    $scope.myButtonId = 'fleetmanagerBackButton';
}
```

and use below in HTML view

```
<a ng-href="{{myUrl}}" title="URL" ng-attr-id="{{myButtonId}}" ></a>
```

Hope this help!